# What are some examples of function that approach a max but never exceed it?

Tags: functions

I'm working on a project where I need to record and then score a number of problem areas for different organizations. Imagine an inspection or something where the number of "minor problems" is recorded, then a score up to a max I can set is assigned based on that number of problems.

This is not my image, but it's similar to what I need. I would like to be able to define the max Y value (even as a decimal), the x value at which the Y value reaches max, and if possible, the "flatness" of the curve so that I can refine how much the first few "problems" affect the score.

(I see that this example appears to be asymptotic to 100, I would like this one to actually reach that max at a value I can define)

[image: example graph]

Any help would be awesome! Thanks so much.

Comment: $y = 100-b^{-x}$ where $b>1$.

Comment: You can't exceed the supremum --- that is the definition.  You don't necessarily have a maximum.

Comment: Yeah, but in layman's terms, 'maximum' should refer to the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), which models how many times an event (in this case, minor problems) occurs in a given timeframe.

The cumulative distribution function for this is given by:

$$e^{-r} \sum_{i = 0}^{k} \frac{r^i}{i!}$$

where $r$ is the mean / average number of errors in the given timeframe, and this will give you the probability that $k$ errors or fewer will occur. You should be able to implement this using code.

Note that probabilities always range from $0$ to $1$, so multiply this by the maximum score.